# How to understand this formula in Direct Construction of Minimal Acyclic Subsequential Transducers?

Tags: algorithm, fst

In this paper "Direct Construction of Minimal Acyclic Subsequential Transducers" https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=690EBF51DD6D52AB9160723AAE3A9541?doi=10.1.1.24.3698&rep=rep1&type=pdf

1. in Definition 3, what does !(u(r,a)) mean? I can't understand this formula as a whole.

[image]

2 In lemma 3, what does ¬!u(tk,a) mean? It come out without explaination.

[image]

Comment: This is not a tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66: I don't believe that this is a tutoring question; it's a straight-forward and specific question about what a particular piece of mathematical notation means in a specific paper, which is correctly cited. That doesn't make it a good fit for StackOverflow, but the question certainly could not be improved by adding "what you have tried so far".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same author's earlier paper, [*Direct Building of Minimal Automaton for a Given List*](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.1915), it is specified (under *Background and Notations*) that

> we use `!μ(r,σ)` to denote that `μ(r,σ)` is defined

I suppose it is the same in this paper.

I can only guess what `¬!μ(r,σ)` might mean; I assume that `¬` is being used as a negation operator, which is what would be usual. That is, it means that `μ(r,σ)` is not defined.

For future reference, questions like this –which really have nothing to do with programming *per se*– should be directed to the StackExchange community [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com) (or possibly to [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com), but *not* to both), but only after ensuring that the question fits the guidelines for those sites. For one thing, those sites allow the use of MathJax, which makes it much easier both for you and for whoever answers to write in mathematical notation.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer really helps! When I wrote the question I can feel that it may not be suitable on this site, but I don't know a better place. Thanks for the guide for where to ask this kind of question.